# C - Eclipse - "Mixed" dialect and ANSI support crash program?

Tags: c, eclipse, c99, ansi-c, dialect

I've been having a strange issue with C in Eclipse. Right-clicking on my project, I go to Properties, C/C++ Build, Settings, Gcc C Compiler Dialect. In the dropdown menu, by default, there's nothing under Language Standard, and my program runs fine. However, by changing to anything else (C90, C99, or C11), the program crashes when run.

Using the debugger, I looked at the disassembly and got a complaint regarding strln() at some memory address and I'm not sure where to proceed from here.

Here's some assembly:

```
mov (%ecx),%al
add $0x1,%ecx
test %al,%al
je 0x75234434 <strlen+97>
test $0x3,%ecx
jne 0x752343df <strlen+12>
...
```

Interestingly, without the dialect specified, by clicking on Miscellaneous, and clicking Support ANSI programs (-ansi) causes the exact same error.

Any and all advice welcome :)

Tracebook as requested:

```
#0  0x752343df in strlen () from C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
#1  0x0044e2bd in __mingw_pformat ()
#2  0x0044ca5f in __mingw_vfprintf ()
#3  0x00417156 in fprintf (__stream=0x752c2980 <msvcrt!_iob+128>, __format=0x4561dc <__register_frame_info+4547036> "%s %.2lf %s %.0lf %.0lf %.2lf %.2lf %.2lf %.2lf ") at c:/mingw/include/stdio.h:246
#4  0x00418893 in skriv_v_profil (tag=0x809fe8, nasta_stat=..., sign=1, variant=2) at ..\src\kortid.c:314
#5  0x00419d65 in kor_tid (tag=0x809fe8, v2=24.25, smax=452, tmax=100000) at ..\src\kortid.c:642
#6  0x00427fdb in gang_tid (tag=0x809fe8, ret_kod=2, tmax=100000, skriv_g3=0, test_finnsg3=0, t_ack=3030.5876288659802) at ..\src\gangtid.c:2617
#7  0x00403215 in kor_tag (taget=0x809fe8, lanken=0x7cc338, riktning=1, result=0x7da1f8, resflg=7) at ..\src\ttt2gtk.c:702
#8  0x00407ff7 in grenkortag (banap=0x28fd6c, grnidx=0, tagtyp=0x7e6ea0, ttpidx=0, riktn=1, resflg=7, stppl=0x0, resp=0x28fd34) at ..\src\ttt2gtk.c:2405
#9  0x004201b8 in main (argc=11, argv=0x7e1b00) at ..\src\gtb.c:991
```

Apologies, I missed copying the second half as the window was really small.

Comment: It would help to see the original C code.

Comment: It's 30+ K lines and we have no idea what's causing the problem, sorry...

Comment: You at least know *where* it's crashing, right?  Can you show that function?  Or at least pare it down to reproduce the error?  Based on your description, dollars to donuts you're invoking undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: Actually I don't because it doesn't tell me. I run the debugger, go past my breakpoints, next thing that comes up is a blank window with "No source available for "strlen() at 0x752343df". View Diassembly...". If there were code available, I would of course have posted it. Any suggestions? Not exactly sure what this means.

Comment: That debugger you're using has a call-stack. Unless you have code that overwrote it and thus blew apart your immediate how-I-got-here history, it will be most-helpful in knowing what was what in helping to discover how you got here. If you have access to `gdb` in console-mode (there should be one in Eclipse) a simple `bt` command should give you your call-stack.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig, I didn't know about that functionality. Does that help or did I copy the wrong data?

Comment: @Rob: that helps; now we just need to see the source in `src\kortid.c` around line 314 (it would help to post the whole function that includes that line).

Comment: Sorry, I missed posting the half of the traceback as the window was small. I take it I look in main, gtb.c, ln: 991?

Comment: @Rob: actually, you want to look at the "highest" frame that's in your source code (frame #4, which is src\kortid.c); that's the line that triggered the segfault.  Everything below that just shows how you got to that line.  Everything above it is part of the standard library, for which you won't have the source.  Based on this trace, it looks like you're calling `fprintf` with a bad argument (either too few arguments, or you have arguments out of order relative to the format string, something like that).

Comment: We found the "source" of the error but it's stupid? We have hundreds fprinf statements with the percent modifier %lf for doubles. Changing a few examples seems to "fix" the issue but not only is it stupid, it also isn't reproducible in a test code sample. So that's not it of course. The line in question is indeed an fprintf statement. I can post it if you like but I'm not sure it's helpful as it's full of function return values and pointers to structures built out of structures...

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the error. One of the variables becomes -1 and highlighted in Eclipse. I have no idea about the details but I think the solution will be very specific and I'll have to find it myself. Thanks to John Bode and WhozCraig for the help, especially regarding the traceback. Life savers, thank you!